# How can I make my images responsive aligned in a scrollable row?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to align my images for a photography portfolio in a single, scrollable row and also want to make them responsive to window resizing and other screen sizes. Essentially to just have them shrink and grow as the screen changes. Previously I had them in a scrollable row but now that I've tried to make them responsive, they just adjust and shrink down and show the entire image gallery without scroll, but are really small since they are all trying to fit inside the window.

Here's what I have so far

```css
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    transition: .3s;

}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: .3s;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.sub-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: auto;
  /*width: 50%;*/
}


.gallery__thumb {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class = "sub-container">
    <figure class="gallery__thumb">
       <img src="highq.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="gallery__thumb">
       <img src="highq.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="gallery__thumb">
       <img src="highq.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>   
    <figure class="gallery__thumb">
       <img src="highq.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>                   
    <figure class="gallery__thumb">
       <img src="highq.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>                                   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get them to scroll up and down? Right now you have it set on the X axis. I had to force a width x height on my side for your images just to see it but when i shrink it down, it still lets me scroll. Again, on the X axis though.

Comment: @Brandon I'm trying to get them to scroll left to right

Comment: hm.. maybe someone else can look. Like i said i plugged in your exact same thing, although i had to force a width and height on the images just to see it but it lets me scroll left to right as i shrink the page down.

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more structure to your question, because like that we don't know how or where that row is placed. In addition I'd suggest using a `flex` row with a fixed height, fixed in the way it takes a certain percentage of its container, and therefore the screen, so your images will take up that height and scroll horizontally like you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider adding a ***min-width*** to the images in *percentage units of measurement*. This will allow the images to grow in size and shrink always keeping the minimum amount of length as a percentage of the parents total width.

In the example below I reset *margin and padding* to **0** using a **universal selector** => `*`, this will remove any *unseen/unwanted* *margin or padding* set by default browser settings for elements.

Then we align the flex sub-container vertically using `align-items: center;` each `figure` element `.gallery__thumb` will set `min-width: 33%`. A slight gap of ***10px margin*** between each remaining `.gallery__thumb` using ***general sibling combinator*** `~` => `.gallery__thumb ~ .gallery__thumb { margin-left: 10px; }`.

Now as you resize the browser there will always be 3 images showing no matter the size of the browser. If you want 4 to show, change to 25%, 5 to 20%, etc... In some cases, you may need to add a calculated measurement using `width: calc(33% - 20px)`, where 20 pixels may represent 10 pixels of left and right margin on a parent container for example.

[See resizing browser GIF](https://gyazo.com/ca3d5af21e17fa91477fb35a9cb10788)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery__thumb ~ .gallery__thumb {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.sub-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery__thumb {
  min-width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <figure class="gallery__thumb">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/260/any" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="gallery__thumb">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/320/260/any" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="gallery__thumb">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/310/280/any" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="gallery__thumb">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/340/280/any" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="gallery__thumb">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/260/any" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you everyone for your help! this did the trick. css is hard.